# ETL with Java code

Tags: java, etl

I need to load data to OLAP cube. Is there some tool where I can write ETL in java code?
(I mean mainly transformation)

Thanks for tips.

Comment: What OLAP? Microsoft OLAP, Pentaho OLAP, some other?

Answer (score 1):

This tool is called text editor. But you can also try talend

Answer (score 0):

Some more information on your question might help.

Have you looked at [Mondrian](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/)? A former colleague rated this tool and spoke very highly of it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what OLAP do You use (Microsoft SSAS, Pentaho OLAP like Fortyrunner mentioned, ...). I believe that the following is true for all OLAP's (for Microsoft SSAS i am sure it is true): You can't load data to OLAP directly. However, You can use whatever tool You like to extract, load, and transform data to destination database. Then use Microsoft SSAS to make cubes/dimensions/fact tables. SSAS itself will process your destination database data and populate it into cube.

You might want to look at open source ETL solution [Talend](http://www.talend.com). It is written in java. You can write your own components also, all You need to know is to write ordinary JAVA code, because inputs and outputs are JAVA types.

Answer (score 0):

OLAP cube is not some specific application. It is based on the array presentation of data. You use three dimensional arrays and sparse array implementation to display relations of your data. Java is a great language for business applications like that.

Tools you can use to do your own development can be:

1. [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)
2. [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport) or [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/project/)
3. some RDBMS would be useful.

There are OLAP implementation solutions you could also try, like:

[Olap4j](http://www.olap4j.org/) and [Pentaho Mondrian](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/) may also be good options, but you will need some preparation time before you learn how to use them.

[instantOLAP](http://www.instantolap.com/) is a commercial program that offers a free license you can try.